# Get content settings for Chrome not from Extension by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know way to get is there plugin on browser or not, but what about whether it's active or blocked. So is it possible to receive content-settings for chrome not from extension( for extension- ContentSetting.get(object details, function callback))?